# Open Telemetry Collector issues exporting trace data to Splunk and/or Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, splunk, opentracing, open-telemetry

I'm trying to capture telemetry information from a .NET Core app to Kafka and then ultimately into Splunk (either via Kafka Connect or via an open-source forwarder like Logstash or Fluentd). Initially, I'm just looking at trace data, but will look at logs and metrics at some stage as well.

I'm keen to test out the Open Telemetry Collector approach, as this is something I'm interested in.

I'm using docker and docker-compose, so I can test out everything locally - see [here](https://github.com/yesmarket/splunk-demo/blob/master/docker-compose.otel-agent.yml) for docker-compose file.

The main issue I'm facing at the moment is getting the Open Telemetry Collector agent to run in docker. I've tried exporting to both Splunk as well as Kafka, but I'm getting errors for both:

When trying to export trace info directly to Splunk using the [splunk_hec exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/splunkhecexporter) as follows:

```
exporters:
  splunk_hec:
    token: "${SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN}"
    endpoint: "${SPLUNK_HEC_URL}"
    source: "otel"
    sourcetype: "otel"
    insecure_skip_verify: true

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [splunk_hec]
```

I'm getting the following error:

> otel     | Error: cannot load configuration: unknown exporters type "splunk_hec" for splunk_hec
>
> otel     | 2021/03/04 05:47:13 application run finished with error: cannot load configuration: unknown exporters type "splunk_hec" for splunk_hec

When trying to export trace info to Kafka using the [kafka exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/exporter/kafkaexporter) as follows:

```
exporters:
  kafka:
    brokers:
      - "${KAFKA_URL}"
    protocol_version: 2.0.0

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [kafka]
```

I'm getting the following error - note I'm using the [landoop/fast-data-dev](https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/fast-data-dev) image for Kafka (as this was used in the first couple tutorials I found) and I'm pretty new to Kafka:

> otel     | Error: cannot setup pipelines: cannot build builtExporters: error creating kafka exporter: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
>
> otel     | 2021/03/04 05:32:08 application run finished with error: cannot setup pipelines: cannot build builtExporters: error creating kafka exporter: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)

My `otel-agent-config.yaml` (which is a WIP) is [here](https://github.com/yesmarket/splunk-demo/blob/master/otel/otel-agent-config.yaml).

Does anyone know what these issues are and how to resolve them...